# Segmented control is showing weird title in first segment

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I have one segmented control. It's showing weird title in first segment. though it happens sometimes not always but I don't know which thing triggers it. Autosize mode is set to proportional to content
here are the snapshots of iphone,storyboard and autolayout constraints

[image: Iphone]

Storyboard
[image: storyboard]

Autolayout Constraints[image: Autolayout constraints]

I have extended SegmentedControl to fulfill a certain requirement here is the code

```
class CustomSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    var current = 0
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        current = self.selectedSegmentIndex
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        if current == self.selectedSegmentIndex{
            self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewController

```
class MatchingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchHolder: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchButton: UIButton!

    enum tabEnum: Int {
        case all = 0
        case iceBreaker
        case tagged
        case connected
    }
    enum buttonTags: Int{
        case searchButton = 101
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTags()
        setupActions()
        setupSegmentControl()
        setupSearchBar()


    }


    func setupTags(){
        self.searchButton.tag = buttonTags.searchButton.rawValue
    }
    func setupActions(){
        self.searchButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didSelect(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    func setupSearchBar() {
        self.searchButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGreen(), for: [])
        self.searchHolder.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.searchHolder.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGreen().cgColor
        self.searchHolder.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.searchTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func setupSegmentControl() {
        segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didSelectTab(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        didSelectTab(segmentControl)
    }



    func didSelectTab(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let value = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
        self.segmentControl.tintColor = UIColor.darkGreen()

        print("selectedIndex \(value)")
        let storyBoard = Global.sharedInstance.storyboard
        let storyBoardId = value == 0 ? "FirstViewControllerID" : "SecondViewControllerID"
        vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyBoardId)

        if let vc = vc {
            vc.setValue(self, forKey: "parentController")
             vc.setValue(value, forKey: "tabIndex")
            self.containerView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
            self.containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
            vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addChildViewController(vc)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                vc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
                vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
                vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
                vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
                ])
            vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        }
    }


    func didSelect(_ sender: UIButton){
        if let tag = buttonTags.init(rawValue: sender.tag){
            switch tag {
            case .searchButton:
                self.searchTextField.endEditing(true)
                startSearch()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your view controller code, associated with CustomSegmentedControl

Comment: This looks like a key from localization. Are your storyboards localized? Do you have a different language/region set on the device that this happened?

Comment: @Krunal I have updated my code.

Comment: @Losiowaty storyboard is not localized sir. device language is set to english sir.

Comment: @Losiowaty and the device it was currently being tested is in US

Comment: replace `@IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!` with `@IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: CustomSegmentedControl!`

Comment: Your remaining code is fine. There isn't anything wrong exept class for Segment Interface builder.

Comment: @krunal This weird names appears sometimes not always. may be you are right that wrong class is the reason for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the scenes, Xcode builds localizable.strings files for your storyboards that map the strings for your view objects to entries using object-ids. What you show looks like the string name of one of those strings. If you edit your storyboard's .strings file and change one of those string mappings (like `"KkS-S7-SCw.segmentTitle" = "All"`) then you might get the very results you are seeing. My guess is some sort of mess-up with the localizable strings that are under the surface for Storyboards.

Comment: thanks for the information. lemme play with the strings and get back to you

Comment: I checked the string  and tried to modified seems fine. when i first opened it it looks like  <segments>
                                    <segment title="All"/>
                                    <segment title="Ice Breaker"/>
                                    <segment title="Tag"/>
                                    <segment title="Connected"/>
                                </segments>

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's something about the SegmentedControl's "Object ID" (blue arrow on image).
Verify if the "Class" attribute is properly set with your subclass in Interface Builder (red arrow on image).

Check if with default class the problem continues to happen.
If it solves the problem then the error should be in your subclass code.
If not, it will be even stranger.

[Class and Object ID properties locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwzyq.png)

Comment: That weird title is indeed Object id. I just checked. but the class was given properly. As @Krunal suggested in comments that I have given wrong IBOutlet class in my viewcontroller. That may be the reason it showed me. I cannot verify right now. As this happens very rarely. during putting this question i ran the project and it was working fine

Comment: There is the possibility that it is a problem related to XCode itself and the building process...
Sometimes cleaning the project (shift + command + K) and the build folder (option + shift + command + K) solves some weird and unexplainable problems

Comment: That happened runtime bro. The build was uploaded to diawi.com and the same build installed twice on that phone. First time it worked as expected second time it gives the object-ID title